# A property of the resultant

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, integral-domain

Let $A$ be a domain. There's a problem in Lorenzini's *An Invitation to Arithmetic Geometry*, which states that if $f,g\in A[y]$, then we can find $u,v\in A[y]$ with $\deg u<\deg g$ and $\deg v<\deg f$ s.t.

$$uf+vg = \textrm{Res}(f,g).$$

Is there an easy way to see this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ has degree $m$ and $g$ has degree $n$, say $$
f = a_0y^m + a_1y^{m-1} + \cdots + a_m$$ $$g = b_0y^n + b_1y^{n-1}+ \cdots + b_n$$ Then the resultant of $f$ and $g$ is the determinant of the $(n + m)\times (n+m)$ Sylvester matrix:

$$Res(f,g) = \det \left(\begin{matrix} a_0 & a_1 & \cdots & a_m & 0 &\cdots & 0\\
0 & a_0 & a_1 & \cdots & a_m &\cdots & 0\\
& & & \ddots\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & a_0 & a_1 &\cdots & a_m \\
b_0 & b_1 &\cdots & b_n &0 &\cdots & 0\\
0 &b_0 &b_1&\cdots & b_n &\cdots & 0\\
& & & \ddots\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & b_0 & b_1 & \cdots &b_n
\end{matrix}\right).$$ To make notation easy, let $A$ denote this matrix. Note that $$A\left(\begin{matrix} y^{n+m-1}\\ y^{n+m-2}\\\vdots\\ y\\ 1\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}y^{n-1}f\\ y^{n-2} f\\\vdots\\ yf\\f\\y^{m-1}g\\y^{m-2}g\\\vdots\\yg\\ g\end{matrix}\right).$$ If $B$ is the [adjugate matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $A$, that is, $BA = \det(A)\,Id = Res(f,g)\,Id$, then multiplying both sides of this equality on the left by $B$ gives $$ 
Res(f,g)\left(\begin{matrix} y^{n+m-1}\\ y^{n+m-2}\\\vdots\\ y\\ 1\end{matrix}\right) = B \left(\begin{matrix}y^{n-1}f\\ y^{n-2} f\\\vdots\\ yf\\f\\y^{m-1}g\\y^{m-2}g\\\vdots\\yg\\ g\end{matrix}\right).$$ If we then look in particular at the bottom row of this equality, you get an expression of the form $$Res(f,g) = uf + vg,$$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks. I guessed the adjugate matrix is going to come into play. This is the one particular construction in linear algebra that for some reason I've never learned how to use properly...

Answer (score 1):

How easy this is may depend on how you define the resultant.  A key fact is that if $f = q g + r$ for polynomials $q$ and $r$ with $\deg(r) \le \deg(f)$, then $\text{Res}(f,g) = a^{\text{deg}(f)-\text{deg}(r)} \text{Res}(r,g)$ where $a$ is the leading coefficient of $g$.

Comment: The book really just gives the determinant and nothing more. It also proves that it's zero iff f,g share a factor.