# Relatively prime polynomials over integrally closed domain are(?) relatively prime over the fraction field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know that the following holds:

> **Lemma.** Let $R$ be an integrally closed domain and $K$ its field of fractions. Let $f \in R[X] \setminus R$ monic. Suppose that there exist $g,h \in K[X] \setminus K$ such that $f=gh$. Then $g,h \in R[X]$. In particular, if $f$ is irreducible over R, then it's irreducible over K.

I have to prove the following:

> Let $R$ be an integrally closed domain and $f,g \in R[X]$ relatively prime (i.e. there is no $h \in R[X] \setminus R$ such that $h|f$ and $h|g$). Then there are $p,q \in R[X]$ with $pf+qg \in R \setminus \{0\}$.

**Question**: is it true that if $f,g$ (*not necessarily monic*) are relatively prime in $R$, then they are relatively prime in $K$?

If this is true, then I can solve my exercise, since by Bezout's identity I can find $p',q' \in K[X] \setminus K$ such that $p'f+q'g = 1$, and then it's sufficient to multiply $p'f+q'g$ by the product of all the denominators of the coefficients of $p'$ and $q'$.

Comment: Actually I'd have expected that there is no non-unit with that property.

Comment: Well, actually I think that **every** unit trivially divides every element. Doesn't it?

Comment: I said non-unit, which means that degree zero polynomials are allowed whether they are not invertible.

Comment: No. I mean that relatively prime definition should be as follows: there is no non-invertible $h\in R[X]$ such that... (Anyway, you can take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241667/a-property-of-the-resultant, but I don't know if it is helpful as long as you want to get a non-zero resultant.)

Comment: Maybe this sounds stupid, but...can there be a unit in $R[X]$ which is not a unit of $R$? If it can't be, then my definition is even stronger than yours.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "stronger", but I can't see why $2X$ and $2X+2$ are coprime in $\mathbb Z[X]$ as both are divisible by a non-unit, namely $2$.

Comment: By "stronger" I mean the same thing (I'm sure) it means to you, the problem is that I was of course wrong: if it is true that every unit of $R[X]$ is an element of $R$, of course your definition is stronger than mine. Probably I should go to bed...it's quite late here, and I'm clearly too tired for maths...